# .htacces to show name rather than id

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a table containing catname(catename) and catid(23).
right now in url I am showing catid=23.
I have defined a rewrite rule which show example.com/13 in url for this : example.com?catid=13
Is it possible to achieve following

In url : example.com/catename 
Actual page it is showing : example.com?catid=13

Comment: catid and catname is comin dynamically, catid is unique, name can be same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do will be to use urls such as example.com/13-catname if your category name is not unique.
Change your rewrite rule to extract the ID and pass it to the PHP script.

Answer (score 5):

First you want to send the category name also within the URL.

Then use, in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*).html$ product_info.php?catid=$2%1
```

It work for me.

**Another Solution**

If you want to show only `catname`, not `catid`, then you want to create a new field in the table with an unique key. Then save alias name of the category here that you want to show in the URL.

Comment: But I dont want it like example.com/catname/catid it should be like example.com/catname

Comment: If you want to show only carname not catid then you want to create new field in table. then save alias name of category here that you want to show in url.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. You'd need to ensure that `catname` was unique and if it is not, you'd need to add an additional field, permalink/uniqid, to contained a unique and friendly URL alias.

```
RewriteRule ^/(\s+)$ ./index.php?catname=$1
```

You'd need to then check for `catname` in your PHP file and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the suggestion. Now I got it. since catname is not unique two page can have same url, for this I have to ensure that it should be unique. I can add Id in front to make it unique. From such name i can acheive this. thanks a lot.